# Efficient way to randomly select all rows from pandas dataframe corresponding to a column value

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a pandas dataframe containing about 2 Million rows which looks like the following example

```
ID  V1    V2   V3   V4    V5
12  0.2   0.3  0.5  0.03  0.9
12  0.5   0.4  0.6  0.7   1.8
01  3.8   2.9  1.1  1.6   1.5
17  0.9   1.2  1.8  2.6   9.0
02  0.2   0.3  0.5  0.03  0.9
12  0.5   0.4  0.6  0.7   1.8
07  3.8   2.9  1.1  1.6   1.5
19  0.9   1.2  1.8  2.6   9.0
19  0.5   0.4  0.6  0.7   1.8
06  3.8   2.9  1.1  1.6   1.5
17  0.9   1.2  1.8  2.6   9.0
18  0.9   1.2  1.8  2.6   9.0
```

I want to create three subsets of this data such that the column ID is mutually exclusive. And each of the subset includes all rows corresponding to the ID column in the main dataframe.

As of now, I am randomly shuffling the ID column and selecting unique ID's as a list. Using this list I'm selecting all rows that from the dataframe who's ID belong to fraction of the list.

```
import numpy as np
import random 
distinct = list(set(df.ID.values))
random.shuffle(distinct)
X1, X2 = distinct[:1000000], distinct[1000000:2000000] 

df_X1 = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(list(X1))]

df_X2 = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(list(X2))]
```

This is working as expected for smaller data, however for larger data the run doesn't even complete for many hours. Is there a more efficient way to do this? appreciate responses.

Comment: you can try `df['ID'].unique()` to get the unique ids

Comment: Can you explain why a simple slice wont work? For instance, df_X1=df[df['ID']<10000]

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain - set(df.ID.values) does the same

Comment: @DallasLindauer - df_X1=df[df['ID']<10000]  this will work only if there were distinct ID's. The problem here is to select all rows corresponding to a unique list of ID

Comment: @iprof0214 i know that works but if you are dealing with dataframes i believe using the provided functions will surely help in efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I think the slow down is coming in the nested isin list inside the loc slice. I tried a different approach using numpy and a boolean index that seems to double the speed.

First to set up the dataframe. I wasn't sure how many unique items you had so I selected 50. I was also unsure how many columns so arbitrarily selected 10,000 columns and rows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 10000))

ID = np.random.randint(0,50,10000)
df['ID'] = ID
```

Then I try to use mostly numpy arrays and avoid the nested list using a boolean index.

```
# Create a numpy array from the ID columns
a_ID = np.array(df['ID'])

# use the numpy unique method to get a unique array
# a = np.unique(np.array(df['ID']))
a = np.unique(a_ID)

# shuffle the unique array
np.random.seed(100)
np.random.shuffle(a)

# cut the shuffled array in half
X1 = a[0:25]

# create a boolean mask
mask = np.isin(a_ID, X1)

# set the index to the mask
df.index = mask
df.loc[True]
```

When I ran your code on my sample df, times were 817 ms, the code above runs at 445 ms.

Not sure if this helps. Good question, thanks.